# Why are decimal numbers used in bitmasks?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

This is a pretty basic question, and I'm sure that there's an easy answer to it, but I don't know the search term I should be using to look for an answer. Here it goes:

I'm trying to understand how bitmasks work.  On Linux systems there's:

```
struct stat
```

that has a st_mode member that's used to determine whether the file being inspected is a regular file, a directory, a symbolic link, and others.  So, it's possible to write a simple function that you can pass a name to and get whether or not the name represents a directory:

```
16 int isadir( char *name )
17 /*
18  *      calls stat, then masks the st_mode word to obtain the
19  *      filetype portion and sees if that bit pattern is the
20  *      pattern for a directory
21  */
22 {
23         struct stat info;
24 
25         return ( stat(name,&info)!=-1 && (info.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR );
26 }
```

When I look at the bitmask, I see it's represented as follows:

```
/* Encoding of the file mode.  */

#define __S_IFMT        0170000 /* These bits determine file type.  */
```

I thought bitmasks could only have 0s and 1s.  Why is there a 7 in the mask?

Comment: My guess would be the constant is being expressed in octal (base 8)

Comment: All numbers are stored internally as binary numbers. Leading 0 indicates octal. Slightly easier for humans to type in and read. When compiled it ends up as binary.

Comment: This is an important point if you are going to write or read c. Leading zeros are *significant* in integer constants as they set the base. Likewise leading `0x` or `0X` which signify hexadecimal (base 16).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A byte is 8 bits, and can be expressed in decimal (0 to 255), octal (000 to 377), hexadecimal (00 to FF) or binary (00000000 to 11111111). Let's number the bits, from bit 0 to bit 7:

```
76543210
```

Actually a number may be expressed in any base, but mainly octal and hexadecimal are convenient when one want to break down the number into bits ; expressing a byte in octal is easier as

```
 z  y  x
76543210
```

*x* is bits 0 to 2, *y* is bits 3 to 5 and *z* is bits 6 and 7.

Thus in your exemple, `017` octal number is

```
 0   1   7
00 001 111
```

Numbers expressed in octal base (8-base) are easier to be converted to binary. (in hexa that would be `0F`).

In C (...), octal literal numbers start with a leading zero (0...), and in hexadecimal they start with leading `0x` (0x...). As it is easier to *visualize* bits of numbers expressed in octal,

```
022 & 017
```

gives in binary

```
"00 010 010" &
"00 001 111"
```

result can be found out easily

```
"00 000 010"
```

In decimal, that would be `18 & 15`.

Comment: Great!  Thanks for the detailed explanation, it helps a lot.  Looks like I have some reading to do on number systems.

Answer (score 4):

Numbers starting with a leading 0 are octal numbers — this is standard C syntax.

And these can be useful for bitmasks, especially to represent Unix permissions.